# problems when linking objects with g++

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, g++, sdl

I am trying to make a simple obj loader with opengl in c++.
Compiling everything with one command works fine,

```
g++ -o main main.cpp timer.cpp screen.cpp obj_loader.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs` `pkg-config --cflags --libs glu`
```

returns no errors.

compiling objects individually works fine too,

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags --libs` `pkg-config glu --cflags --libs`
g++ obj_loader.cpp -o obj_loader.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags --libs` `pkg-config glu --cflags --libs`
g++ timer.cpp -o timer.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags --libs` `pkg-config glu --cflags --libs`
g++ screen.cpp -o screen.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags --libs` `pkg-config glu --cflags --libs`
```

also returns no errors.

However, when running the final

```
g++ main.o obj_loader.o timer.o screen.o -o main
```

I get a bunch of undefined reference errors:

```
main.o: In function `draw()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `glColor3f'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `glBegin'
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `glVertex2i'
main.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glVertex2i'
main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `glVertex2i'
main.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `glVertex2i'
main.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `glEnd'
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `glClear'
main.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers'
main.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `glFinish'
main.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
timer.o: In function `Timer::start()':
timer.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
timer.o: In function `Timer::pause()':
timer.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
timer.o: In function `Timer::unpause()':
timer.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
timer.o: In function `Timer::tick()':
timer.cpp:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
timer.o: In function `Timer::get_ticks()':
timer.cpp:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
screen.o: In function `init()':
screen.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
screen.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `SDL_SetVideoMode'
screen.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `SDL_WM_SetCaption'
screen.o: In function `init_GL()':
screen.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
screen.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
screen.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
screen.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `glOrtho'
screen.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
screen.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
screen.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `glGetError'
screen.o: In function `clean_up()':
screen.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My included libraries are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_opengl.h"

#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
```

and my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
SDL_FLAGS=`sdl-config --cflags --libs`
GL_FLAGS=`pkg-config glu --cflags --libs`

CFLAGS=-c -Wall

FLAGS=$(CFLAGS) $(SDL_FLAGS) $(GL_FLAGS)
LDFLAGS=

SOURCES=main.cpp obj_loader.cpp timer.cpp screen.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *o main
```

Comment: Well, the command line you give as example, the one that doesn't work...doesn't show you linking the required libraries, while the one that does work does.  Your Makefile seems to have exactly the same problem.  I wouldn't expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... all those things being returned by `--libs`? You need those in order to link the final executable correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`sdl-config` and `pkg-config` take two flags: `--cflags` and `--libs`. The first of these flags is needed when you're compiling source files into object files. The second of these flags is needed when you're linking. When you compiled everything with a single command, both phases were handled by a single command, so it was natural that you should pass both `--cflags` and `--libs` to `sdl-config` and `pkg-config` at the same time. Now that you've separated those phases, you need to pass the right option to `sdl-config` and `pkg-config` at the right time.

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config glu --cflags`
g++ obj_loader.cpp -o obj_loader.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config glu --cflags`
g++ timer.cpp -o timer.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config glu --cflags`
g++ screen.cpp -o screen.o -c -Wall `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config glu --cflags`

g++ main.o obj_loader.o timer.o screen.o -o main `sdl-config --libs` `pkg-config glu --libs`
```

In your makefile, this means configuring the variables as follows: (I've also made a few other minor fixes to your Makefile)

```
CC=g++
LD=g++

CFLAGS=-c -Wall $(shell sdl-config --cflags) $(shell pkg-config glu --cflags)
LDFLAGS=$(shell sdl-config --libs) $(shell pkg-config glu --libs)

SOURCES=main.cpp obj_loader.cpp timer.cpp screen.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o main
```

There's lots more to critique about your Makefile -- you could probably eliminate most of the action lines here, because GNU Make has them built-in as implicits. You probably need to add rules that specify the dependencies of the `.o` files -- each `.cpp` file probably includes `.h` files, and make needs to know to recompile the `.cpp` files when the `.h` files they depend on change.

Comment: And the makefile could use `CFLAGS:=$(shell sdl-config --cflags) etc.` to avoid re-running the backtick shell commands for every .o that gets compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `-llibraryname` to tell g++ to link with opengl. I would have expected to see this on the g++ line that builds main itself (i.e. the line that ends in 'main'). As far as I know, the .o files by themselves do not contain information about where to find the libraries to resolve their references. That information must be passed in as `-l` switches on the command line.